# Did the US Government try to use EMF rays to remotely affect the mental functions of their targets between 1978-1986?

Tags: cia, mind-control

In the book *Triumph of Evil*<sup>1</sup>, Austin Murphy describes a US Government project to remotely affect the mental functions of people in enemy countries. (My emphasis and footnotes added)

> ... Keeler (1989) reports that the CIA had an Operation Pique that was designed to **affect the mental attitudes and behavior of employees at nuclear power plants in communist Eastern Europe**, implying some intent to cause a nuclear meltdown/holocaust. Given the bizarre and otherwise virtually inexplicable behavior of the employees who caused the nuclear disaster at Chernobyl in the Soviet Union in 1986 (Medvedev, 1991)<sup>3</sup>, it is possible that the USA's Operation Pique may have had something to do with it.

Murphy cites an article, *Remote Mind Control Technology*<sup>2</sup> by A. Keeler, who explains:

> Propagation of microwaves has been very well studied
>   and is very sophisticated, e.g., a two inch beam can be sent from
>   a satellite, point to point, to a receiving dish on earth; and,
>   it was reported in 1978, that the CIA had a program called
>   Operation Pique, which included bouncing radio signals or
>   microwaves off of the ionosphere to affect the mental functions
>   of people in selected areas, including Eastern European nuclear
>   installations.

Keeler doesn't provide a direct citation, so it is unclear which, if any, of the sources were used as the basis for this statement.

### Question

Is there evidence that there was:

- a United States government operation

  - designed to remotely affect the mental functions of targeted people
  - by using EMF / radio waves
- that was in operation between 1978 and 1986?

Note that this question is *not* about whether or not this operation may have played a role in Chernobyl. This question is about evidence for Operation Pique (regardless of actual targets). The claim that there was "bizarre and otherwise virtually inexplicable behavior of the employees who caused the nuclear disaster at Chernobyl" [is disputed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernobyl_disaster#Causes).

---

<sub>**References:**</sub>

<sub><sup>1</sup> Austin Murphy, *The triumph of evil: The reality of the USA's Cold War victory* (Fucecchio, Italy: European Press Academic Publishing, 2000), 43-44. Retrieved from pp. 24-25 of the PDF copy of the book available at https://redscans.files.wordpress.com/2011/09/austin-murphy-the-triumph-of-evil.pdf.</sub>

<sub>The following references are duplicated from the bibliography of the above-named reference, and links are provided when I've identified the content freely available on the Internet.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> Keeler, A. "Remote Mind Control Technology." *Full Disclosure* 15 (1989), 11. Retrieved from http://www.spunk.org/texts/altern/pub/keith/sp000435.txt.</sub>

<sub><sup>3</sup> Medvedev, G (translated by E. Rossiter). *The truth about Chernobyl*. Basic Books: New York (1991).</sub>

Comment: Chernobyl doesn't seem that strange--it's less of an anomaly than the Challenger disaster and the bosses were much less accountable in Russia than in the US.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Or any of the aviation accidents where the question 'what on earth were they thinking' is only answerable because the cockpit voice recorder survived the crash.

Comment: Also it seems very unlikely that microwave beams (even if they could affect mental function) could penetrate a reinforced concrete building or a metal roof.

Comment: Please note that this question is about evidence for/against Operation Pique, regardless of actual targets. I've updated the question to clarify this scope.

Comment: @Dan: I want to improve the title, so it actually summarises the claim, but I realise I haven't quite understood it. It could be (a) "Did the CIA have an project called Operation Pique?" The problem with that is there could well have been an innocuous project called that. (In the same way HAARP does exists, but doesn't do what people claim.)

Comment: It could be (b) "Did the CIA have a project to remotely affect the behaviour of enemy power plant operators?" I think that is a better question. Is that about right?

Comment: You've indicated it is not (c) "Did the CIA successfully cause Chernobyl through remote mind control?"

Comment: The only question I actually care about is (d) "Can you perform remote mind control using EMF waves?"

Comment: @Oddthinking (b) I'd what I'm asking, but in combination with the means of (d). (d) is an interesting question but requires much more scientific data, much of which is unlikely to be publicly available due to ethical regulations in research involving human subjects. Except in (b) replace CIA with United States government, as I don't particularly care if it was a military or intelligence community operation, and it is not limited to power plant operators.

Comment: @Oddthinking see my latest edit (I only changed the final question). Is that better?

Comment: If the question is better, please feel free to edit the title to make this post clearer. I'm not sure how to summarize it further. The three bullets are the central parts of the claim I'm seeking to find evidence for/against. I'm not interested in mind control as much as any disruption of mental function that could cause erratic, careless, unusual, or otherwise altered behavior.

Comment: Is the question: "did the government have this program" or "is there any chance of it working".  I wouldn't be surprised if the first is true, the CIA did a lot of crazy things.  But the second definitely isn't.

Comment: @TheBlackCat the first question is what I'm asking (did the US government have a program with these capabilities within the years specified?). I indented the bullets in the question to hopefully clarify this even more. Not sure how else I can make the question any clearer.

Comment: @Dan: It would not surprise me to find that some government agency had an experimental program to test the possibility of such a thing.  I would be absolutely astounded (and I have some background in computational neurobiology) to discover that it actually works.

Comment: *"Triump of Evil"* he-he

Comment: @defaultlocale good catch. Perhaps it was [a Freudian slip for Oddthinking....](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/revisions/37380/6) :P

Comment: Well, now that the question and title have been edited, it's trivially true: the CIA and many other groups, government and other, did try to use EMF to influence the behavior of people.  The process used is called television :-)  And radio, of course: remember Radio Free Europe?

Comment: The trouble with this kind of claim is that there is probably literally no evidence. Someone invents this out of thin air, and of course there is no evidence to support it and also no evidence against it, because nobody else has ever written anything about it.

Comment: If there truly is no evidence, then I agree. But for all I know, a declassified document obtained in a FOIA request is floating around where someone failed to blackout mention of this project, or parts of it have become public knowledge for other reasons. I couldn't find anything reliable in a Google search, but it shows up in some odd places that make me think it wasn't invented by Keeler (some of this was edited out of my question to make it more concise).

Comment: "Operation Pique" is listed in the index of this book. I suspect it may be where Keeler got the idea from, but cannot access the page in the body of the text: https://books.google.com/books?id=vtwgAQAAIAAJ

Answer (score 1):

The statement that "a 2-inch beam [of microwaves] can be sent from a satellite, point to point, to a receiving dish on earth" is false. The limit here is diffraction across the transmitter. Being able to resolve 2 inches from orbit for visible light would require mirror bigger than the Hubble space telescope. Doing the same for microwaves would need a dish hundreds of times bigger because of the longer wavelength. Full technical details are in http://ceeserver.cee.cornell.edu/wdp2/cee6100/6100_monograph/mono_10_Fa12_microwave.pdf. This is about receiving rather than transmitting, but the maths is the same in either direction. See the end for some figures for a typical real-world system, which can manage a beam width of 1.8 degrees. At a range of 200km that would be a circle around 6km in diameter. And of course that is just the "-3dB point", which means the signal is only half as strong there.

Comment: I'm not saying you are wrong, but this was unconvincing.  What part of that document supports what you are claiming?  What about MASERs?

Comment: Masers are subject to the same basic physics of diffraction as any other EM source.

Comment: That is helpful to know, but does not answer the question about whether or not there was a US government operation within a certain time frame that attempted to alter mental functions using EMF / radio waves (regardless of its technical infeasibility).